# Error al ejecutar una función ifelse con múltiples condiciones

Tags: r

Estoy realizando una función ifelse con múltiples condiciones.
Quiero que si mis valores tienen un valor por encima de 4 le añada en una nueva columna el I pero si no y tiene un valor par en la variable PPC_PatientCode sea IIA, de lo contrario IIB.
Para ello he creado el siguiente código.

```
    TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Rama_estudio<-ifelse(TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso>4,"I",
                                          (TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso<4 | 
                                           TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean_NO_cumplidora$PPC_PatientCode%%2==0),"IIA","IIB")
```

No obstante obtengo este error:

```
       Error in ifelse(TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso > 4, "I", (TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso <  :
```

Me gustaría saber donde está el error.
Gracias
unused arguments ("IIA", "IIB")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es que no funciona de la manera que lo estás planteando, la segunda condición en realidad debería ser otro `ifelse()`, es decir tienes que "anidar" los `ifelse()`:

```
TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Rama_estudio <- ifelse(TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso > 4, 
                                               "I",
                                               ifelse(TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean$Average_of_Uso<4 | TELEADHERENCIA_USO_mean_NO_cumplidora$PPC_PatientCode%%2==0,
                                                      "IIA",
                                                      "IIB")
)
```

Comment: Funciona genial, muchas gracias Patricio